# Firebase Functions with TypeScript - Expected at least 1 arguments, but got 0 or more

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I was using Firebase Functions with javascript before and everything was working fine. Now i translated my code to typescript and when i try to update my functions, in one of them it complains about the following error:

> Expected at least 1 arguments, but got 0 or more.

The block of code which causes the problem is this one:

```
  size  =  array.size;
  if (size  ===  0) {
  return;

 } else {
  array.forEach((doc  :  any) => {
  docRefCarsDetails.push(db.collection('cars').doc(doc.get('licensePlate')));
 })

  return  Promise.resolve(db.runTransaction(transaction  => {
    return  Promise.resolve(transaction.getAll(...docRefCarsDetails)); // <-- this is the problem
 }))

 }
```

And as you see i even tried to check the size to make sure that it will not happen.

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
return;
```

To

```
return null;
```

**UPDATE**

Or try this

```
db.runTransaction(transaction  => {
  return  transaction.getAll(...docRefCarsDetails); 
})
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your reply. This suggestion did not work... Do you have any other idea?

Comment: Can you add the original java code for those two lines please?

Answer (score 0):

I found a comment that Help me. it is working well.

**const corsHandler = cors({ origin: true });** // this is the solution

> ```
> import cors from "cors";
> const corsHandler = cors({ origin: true }); // this is the solution
>
> // allow cors in http function
> export const myFunction = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
> corsHandler(req, res, async () => {
>
> // your method body
>
>  });
> });
> ```